# Posting form data to the same page

Tags: php, forms, action

I want to post form-data to the same page where the form is at, but since the url looks like this **domain.com/index.php?id=foo** , $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] returns index.php. When I set form action equal to domain.com/index.php?id=foo, it doesn't wotk either. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just leave your `action=""` attribute in your form **empty**

now, to  actually submit your form, set an `<input type="submit" name="your button">`

and in your php script, just check if the button has been submitted with a simple isset function, like so.

```
if(isset($_POST['yourbutton'])){
    // all in the same page
}
```

Comment: Not including the action attribute opens the page up to iframe clickjacking attacks. You can read more about it here: http://blog.andlabs.org/2010/03/bypassing-csrf-protections-with.html

Comment: Hi, I understand this approach can be exploited. As is any form without action. But this attack is through CSS rendering and not related to PHP's domain. If you have a better approach you can take time to answer this and maybe OP can choose yours as accepted

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post form data to the same page where the form is set, just leave the `action` value empty.

Example :

```
<form method="post" action="">
     ... 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" id="foo" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
 ...
```

domain.com/index.php?id=foo and domain.com/index.php are on the same page

`if ($_post['#foo']);{ // if posted
echo $_post['$var']} // echo input`